# Filter in nested list json return only one value

Tags: android, list, kotlin, filter, nested

My JSON is something like this :

```
[{
    "id": 0001,
    "date": "2021-11-16T20:44:43",
    "category": [
      01
    ],
   "startdate": "2021-12-11"
}
{
    "id": 0002,
    "date": "2021-11-16T20:44:43",
    "category": [
      01,03
    ],
   "startdate": "2021-12-11"
}
]
```

I want to filter by category.
Here is my code in my adapter :

```
 var list = mutableListOf<MyDataItem>()
 var listFiltered = mutableListOf<MyDataItem>()

 fun setDataList(list: List<MyDataItem>) {
        this.list = list.toMutableList()
        var  listFiltered = list?.filter { item ->
            item.category.all { it == "01" }
        }.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentItem = listFiltered[position]
        holder.binding.txtDate.text = currentItem.startdate
        holder.binding.txtTitle.text = currentItem.title.rendered

    }
```

I get only the first value... where did I get it wrong ??

Comment: Remove the `var` inside setDataList. Btw you can also change your `mutableListOf<MyDataItem>` to `listOf<MyDataItem>`.

Comment: yes thanks, a bad copy/paste ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use `.any` instead of `.all`

**All** will require all elements to be "01" -> which is true for first item

**Any** will return true if any of the given elements matches

Comment: I've already tried but I get no result at all...

Comment: try logging your categories and see what you get, In JSON you provided they are numbers but you are comparing as they were strings

Comment: Oh i see the problem you are not returning or setting the filtered list in your `setDataList` it is local variable there

Comment: my bad, it works just fine with the var removed and the any instead of all :) So it should be fun setDataList(list: List<MyDataItem>) {
        this.list = list.toMutableList()
        listFiltered = list?.filter { item ->
            item.category.any { it == "01" }
        }.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }